# How to work hash_hmac function in codeigniter or laravel?

Tags: laravel, codeigniter

> How to work hash_hmac function in codeigniter or laravel with example

Comment: Please tell us whats your problem, what kind of error do you get and what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Work On Php So, you Can use in codeigniter or laravel.

**Synatx :**

> string hash_hmac( $algo, $msg, $key, $raw_opt );

**Code :**

```
<?php 
echo hash_hmac('md5','hash hmac example','DATA'); 
?>
```

**Ans :**

> 9c9c195ece5f36ea04df7cf5658baa25

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
public function makeHash(Request $request)
    {
        $request->user()->fill([
            'password' => Hash::make($request->newPassword)
        ])->save();
    }
```

also add, `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;`

This way you can make the hash.